# Air 3.7 iPhone app rejected due to a blank, black screen upon launch

Tags: iphone, ios6, air, launch

I recently got my iPhone app rejected and the reason is below:

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.3, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, the app displayed a blank, black screen upon launch. Please see the attached screenshot/s for more information. The steps to reproduce are: 1. Launch app 2. Bug encountered

I use FlashDevelop and the latest Apache Flex + Air SDK 3.7 + swfversion=20. I don't have an iPhone 5 to test on but I've tested the application on a 3GS, iPod touch (4th gen.) on IOS 4.3, 5.1 and 6.1.3 (latest) and the application works on all of them.

The attached screenshot mentioned above is here:

[image]

As it shows, the "blank" screen is actually a deep blue one, which the color I've set to my project's background.

I didn't make any special modifications in the code to support iPhone 5 to be honest, and the project dimensions were set to 640x960, but I did include the Default-568h@2x.png, and it shows inside the .ipa at Payload/Myapp.app/

In almost all the iPhone 5 discussions I've read online, theat launch problem is due to the Default-568h@2x.png not being there in the root of the release .ipa, but I'm sure it does exist on my ipa. Also, I have request high resolution set to high, and the Info.plist has the correct DTPlatformVersion (6.0) and DTSDKName (iphoneos6.0).

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find any solution so far? Thanks, Hannes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an iPhone 5 and the error turned tobe this error:

"Error #3747: Multiple application domains are not supported on this operating system."

more information here:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4736711#4736711

The strange thing is that it didn't show up even while using debug mode on iPhone 5, it only showed up while using add-hoc version.

Anyway, I was embedding a swf file (loading animation) and changed that to loading the swf instead and of course proceeded after loading complete.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Flex, use "splashScreenImage"-property of your application. To ensure all resolutions are satisfied, simply use MultiDPI-Ressource.

Some examples can be found at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-8000.html

Comment: Thank you.I'm using pure AS3 not Flex.